# EF 6 programmatic Migration with custom connection string

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, .net-4.5

I have an EF6 code first implementation with migrations enabled and a single initial migration.  I created a method to programmatically run the migration that looks like the following:

```
public void RunMigration()
{
    var migrationConfiguration = new DataAccess.Migrations.Configuration();
    var migrator = new System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator(migrationConfiguration);
    migrator.Update();
}
```

When I got to testing I have several configured connection strings in the App.config.  My Question:

**How do I tell the DbMigrator what connection string to use?**

update:
I suppose the catch is doing this without extending DbMigrator.

Comment: I guess it would also be useful for me to check out how EF7 is doing it, since I will have to reproduce this there soon too.

Comment: The connection is the same as the target DbContext.

Comment: Sure, but there is no exposed way of sending in the dbContext with a different connection.  I found an **internal** constructor that would be usefull.  Not sure what the reasoning for internalizing the following DbMigrator constructor was:

`internal DbMigrator(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration, DbContext usersContext)`

It _seems_ that there is no way to just use the class, I need to create a concrete implementation.

Comment: Now that I get into it, everything I want to use on DbMigrator is internal so extending the class seems like it was not meant to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So unless someone comes up with a better answer: In EF6 there is no working way as of EF 6.1.3 to specify runtime connection strings for programmatic database migrations.  I think the only thing I can see is that I will need to generate an sql script and programmatically run it at time of database setup.  The issue with this is that I either have to compile in the text or deploy it with the binary.

Answer (score 3):

I Use

```
var migrator = new DbMigrator(new DbMigrationsConfiguration { TargetDatabase = new DbConnectionInfo("MyConnectionStringHere")});
migrator.Update();
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you would set `migrationConfiguration.TargetDatabase` to a `DbConnectionInfo`.

One of the constructors for `DbConnectionInfo` takes a connection string.
See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbconnectioninfo.dbconnectioninfo(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbConnectionInfo.)

It looks like the easiest way to actually use this is to modify your `DataAccess.Migrations.Configuration` class to use the constructor with connection string.

Comment: While that sounds straight forward. I still get the error that it cannot find the default named connection string.

Comment: I'll do some tests when I'm back in front of the computer tonight and see if I can get something working.

Answer (score 1):

You can set dbConnectionInfo:

```
migrationConfiguration.TargetDatabase = new DbConnectionInfo(connectionString);
```

full code:

```
public void RunMigration(string connectionString)
{
    var migrationConfiguration = new DataAccess.Migrations.Configuration();
migrationConfiguration.TargetDatabase = new DbConnectionInfo(connectionString);
    var migrator = new System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator(migrationConfiguration);
    migrator.Update();
}
```

**Importan!: make sour you don't set connection name in dbContext initializer.**

Answer (score 0):

I recently needed to do this, my solution was to create a custom Configuration class. The full code base works perfectly for me.

```
    public class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<Context>
{
    public void Init()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;            
    }
    public Configuration()
    {
        Init();
    }

    protected override void Seed(Context context)
    {
        //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.
        //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method
        //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data.
    }
    public static void UpdateDatabase()
    {
        try
        {
            var config = new Configuration();
            UpdateDatabase(config);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.writeLog("UpdateDatabase", ex);
        }
    }

    public Configuration(DbConnectionInfo db)
    {
        Init();
        TargetDatabase = db;
    }
    public static void UpdateDatabase(DbConnectionInfo db)
    {
        try
        {
            var config = new Configuration(db);
            UpdateDatabase(config);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.writeLog("UpdateDatabase", ex);
        }
    }
    private static void UpdateDatabase(Configuration config)
    {
        var migrator = new DbMigrator(config);
        var pending = migrator.GetPendingMigrations();
        if (pending.Count() > 0)
            migrator.Update();
    }
}
```

}

This offers both a default that uses the connection string specified in the DataContext as well as option to pass the connection.

Default Call

```
Configuration.UpdateDatabase();
```

Override with passing connection info

```
var offlineCon = new System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbConnectionInfo("connection string","provider");
Configuration.UpdateDatabase(offlineCon);
```

where connection string is your specific connection string and provider the data provider e.g. System.Data.SqlClient